Undefined resource string ID:0x80131621
lleva un buen rato en esto, y nada tiene sentido, es una app de C#, en local funciona OK, pero al subirlo a AKS sale este error, no temgo idea de porque,
var data = (
    from cm in context.Cita
    join a in context.Agenda on cm.IdAgenda equals a.IdAgenda
    where cm.IdCita == request?.Mensaje?.IdCita
    select new { agenda = a, cita = cm }
).FirstOrDefault();

cuando hago todas las peticiones desde local, no hay ninguna incoveniente, pero al subir a AKS, no funciona nada, ademas de ser exactamente la misma DB
Undefined resource string ID:0x80131621
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.RuntimeHelpers.CompileMethod(RuntimeMethodHandleInternal method)
   at System.Linq.Expressions.Compiler.LambdaCompiler.CreateDelegate()
   at System.Linq.Expressions.Compiler.LambdaCompiler.Compile(LambdaExpression lambda)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.RelationalShapedQueryCompilingExpressionVisitor.VisitShapedQuery(ShapedQueryExpression shapedQueryExpression)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.ShapedQueryCompilingExpressionVisitor.VisitExtension(Expression extensionExpression)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.RelationalShapedQueryCompilingExpressionVisitor.VisitExtension(Expression extensionExpression)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.QueryCompilationContext.CreateQueryExecutor[TResult](Expression query)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.Database.CompileQuery[TResult](Expression query, Boolean async)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryCompiler.CompileQueryCore[TResult](IDatabase database, Expression query, IModel model, Boolean async)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryCompiler.<>c__DisplayClass9_0`1.<Execute>b__0()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.CompiledQueryCache.GetOrAddQuery[TResult](Object cacheKey, Func`1 compiler)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryCompiler.Execute[TResult](Expression query)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.EntityQueryProvider.Execute[TResult](Expression expression)

este es mi docker file
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:8.0 AS builder
WORKDIR /app
COPY . ./
RUN dotnet restore
RUN dotnet publish api -c Release -o out

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:8.0
# Update package lists
RUN echo "deb http://deb.debian.org/debian/ bookworm main contrib" > /etc/apt/sources.list && \
  echo "deb-src http://deb.debian.org/debian/ bookworm main contrib" >> /etc/apt/sources.list && \
  echo "deb http://security.debian.org/ bookworm-security main contrib" >> /etc/apt/sources.list && \
  echo "deb-src http://security.debian.org/ bookworm-security main contrib" >> /etc/apt/sources.list
RUN sed -i'.bak' 's/$/ contrib/' /etc/apt/sources.list
RUN apt-get update; apt-get install -y ttf-mscorefonts-installer fontconfig
# Update font cache
RUN fc-cache -f -v
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=builder /app/out .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "api.dll"]

